# Using dictionary notation to get xml values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I've got XML, and would like to get the value of a node using array/data table like notation

```
<Response>
  <Outcome>
    <KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu>
      <Key>Icon</Key>
      <Value>
        <DataType>System.String</DataType>
        <Field>Icon</Field>
        <Value>O</Value>
      </Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu>
    <KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu>
      <Key>IconDescription</Key>
      <Value>
        <DataType>System.String</DataType>
        <Field>IconDescription</Field>
        <Value>Old</Value>
      </Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu>
    <KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu>
      <Key>IconLongDescription</Key>
      <Value>
        <DataType>System.String</DataType>
        <Field>IconLongDescription</Field>
        <Value>Older</Value>
      </Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu>
  </Outcome>
</Response>
```

I want to do something like `outcome.Key[IconDescription].Value` to give me a value of "Old"

Comment: What language is this referring to? What attempts have you made?

Comment: Using c#, I have tried converting the XML to an array to get the data like that, but that failed

Comment: What you posted isn't a table-like or dictionary notation. It's something specific to your application. The name of an XML element doesn't specify any kind of behaviour. Just because one element is named `Key` and another `Value` doesn't mean they are part of a table or dictionary.

Comment: Post the C# code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Given how regular this XML is, you can deserialize it to concrete classes and write code that converts them to the form you want. You could use Linq to XML to load the string and transform it too. On the other hand, this schema is rather wasteful. Schema information like the data type should be part of an XSD, not the document itself. `Icon`, `IconDescription` etc should be attributes or elements.

Answer (score 0):

Linq provides access to XML through the `XDocument`class which allows you to run XPath against XML. Whilst it is not exactly in the style of your ideal XPath does provide a handy query language for accessing XML nodes, and your tag suggests you might be interested in an XPath solution!

Here is an example of using an `XDocument` to query an XML file. For this example I've simply read a file from a stream.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new FileStream(@"C:\path_to\input.xml", FileMode.Open));

    string desrcription = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Response/Outcome/KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu[Key='IconDescription']/Value/Value").Value;

    Console.WriteLine(desrcription);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```